# How to properly clean up when unloading plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm developing a custom plugin. I'm having issues while debugging using the Plugin Reloader, but the problem is the same when loading and unloading my plugin.

The issue is that scripts seem to keep running when reloading/unloading the plugin. This causes signals firing to call functions that no longer exist, and functions that somehow still exist to try to access UI elements that no longer exist.

What I want to do is to properly remove all signals and functions when unloading the plugin. How would I achieve this?

Comment: You could try disconnecting GUI items from triggering their associated functions by using something like `self.QActionMenu.triggered.disconnect(self.QActionMenuFunction)`

Comment: @Joseph yeah, that's how I solved it currently but that still means I have to keep track of all the signals I'm connecting and then manually disconnecting them all as needed. I guess it makes sense to be doing this, but I was considering if there's a way of cleaning this stuff up in a more robust way.

Comment: Hopefully others can advise on this =)